# PrimeFaces dataTable Composite Component Default Value

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, composite-component

I have the below composite component

```
<ui:component xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="rows" />
        <cc:attribute name="value"
            type="org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel" />
        <cc:attribute name="var" />
        <cc:attribute name="id" />
        <cc:attribute name="rowStyle" default="false"/>
    </cc:interface>

    <cc:implementation>
        <p:dataTable value="#{cc.attrs.value}"
            rendered="#{not empty cc.attrs.value}" id="#{cc.attrs.id}"
            paginator="true" rows="25" 
            currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {startRecord}-{endRecord} of {totalRecords}"
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
            rowsPerPageTemplate="25,50,100" paginatorPosition="bottom"
            lazy="true" rowStyleClass="#{cc.attrs.rowStyle}">
             <c:set target="#{component}" property="var" value="#{cc.attrs.var}"/>
            <cc:insertChildren />
        </p:dataTable>
    </cc:implementation>
</ui:component>
```

My requirement is:
In few cases, I will pass the value of rowStyle otherwise if the value is not passed, it should take the default value.

I have the added the below line in my composite component

```
<cc:attribute name="rowStyle" default="false"/>
```

But it is not working. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that the `default` attribute is for handling the case where the attribute is **not passed**, not the case where the attribute **is null**.

So, given this interface:

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="monkey" />
    <cc:attribute name="food" default="banana" />
</cc:interface>
```

If I invoke it like this, the value of `food` will be `banana`:

```
<barrel monkey="Bonzo" />
```

However, if `myFood` is `null` and I invoke it like this:

```
<barrel monkey="Bonzo" food="#{myFood}" />
```

Then the value of `food` will be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to enter acctual CSS class name into the default.

So, the default value is not true/false flag, but field with actual value.